# C# IsVaild not flipping to False when asp.net edit template validation control group runs and should return false

Tags: c#, asp.net, validationgroup

I have a page that keeps track of company Holidays for our HR system, but right now if you try to edit an end date for a holiday and the user accidentally enters an end date that is before the start date it all still validates to true and allows the edit to be written to the database table.

What am I missing that is making the page always validate to True?  I also have a DetailsView on this page that uses a set of validation controls and it is working and will validate to false when something does not pass the validation.

```
protected void HolidaysDS_Updated(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception != null)
    {
        lblNullUpdate.Text = "One of your updated fields is invalid. Your update did not occur.";
        lblNullUpdate.Visible = true;

        e.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}

protected void gvHolidays_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate("EditValidationControls");

    if (Page.IsValid == false)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    lblNullUpdate.Visible = false;
}
```

That is my current C# that handles the exception if the user passes null in an update and also the event that should be validating the page and checking if everything was valid or not.

```
<h2>Holidays</h2>
        <asp:Label ID="lblHolidayYear" runat="server" Text="Holiday Year:" AssociatedControlID="ddlHolidayYears"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlHolidayYears" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            DataSourceID="HolidayYearDS" DataTextField="HYear" DataValueField="HYear">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:GridView ID="gv_Holidays" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="HolidayID" 
            DataSourceID="HolidaysDS" 
            AllowSorting="True"  
            CssClass="gvhours"
            HeaderStyle-CssClass="header"
            AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alternating"
            SortedAscendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="sortasc-header"
            SortedDescendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="sortdesc-header"
            CommandRowStyle-CssClass="command" 
            PagerStyle-CssClass="page"
            OnRowUpdating="gvHolidays_RowUpdating">
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alternating" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" 
                    ValidationGroup="EditValidationControls" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HolidayID" HeaderText="HolidayID" InsertVisible="False" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="HolidayID" Visible="False" 
                    ShowHeader="False"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HYear" HeaderText="Year" SortExpression="HYear" Visible="false" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HStartDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" 
                    HeaderText="Start Date" SortExpression="HStartDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HEndDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" 
                    HeaderText="End Date" SortExpression="HEndDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HDescription" HeaderText="Description" 
                    SortExpression="HDescription" />
            </Columns>
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="header" />
            <PagerStyle CssClass="page" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortasc-header" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortdesc-header" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Label ID="lblNullUpdate" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" 
            ForeColor="Red" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="HolidaysDS" runat="server" OnInserted="HolidaysDS_Inserted"
            OnUpdated="HolidaysDS_Updated"
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TigerTimeTrackerConnectionString %>" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TigerTimeTracker_ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
            InsertCommand="usp_Holidays_Add_Holiday" 
            InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
            SelectCommand="usp_Holidays_Get_Holidays_By_Year" 
            SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
            UpdateCommand="usp_Holidays_Update_Holiday" 
            UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"> 
               <SelectParameters>
                   <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlHolidayYears" Name="Year" 
                       PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
               </SelectParameters>
               <UpdateParameters> 
                   <asp:Parameter Name="HolidayID" Type="Int32"  />
                   <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlHolidayYears" Name="HYear" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                   <asp:Parameter Name="HStartDate" Type="DateTime" />
                   <asp:Parameter Name="HEndDate" Type="DateTime" />
                   <asp:Parameter Name="HDescription" Type="String" />
               </UpdateParameters>
               <InsertParameters>
                   <asp:Parameter Name="Year" Type="String" />
                   <asp:Parameter Name="StartDate" Type="DateTime" />
                   <asp:Parameter Name="EndDate" Type="DateTime" />
                   <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
               </InsertParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource> 
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="HolidayYearDS" runat="server"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TigerTimeTracker_ConnectionString %>" 
                ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TigerTimeTracker_ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
                SelectCommand="usp_Holidays_Get_Distinct_Holiday_Years" 
                SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" >
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:DetailsView ID="dvHolidays" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" 
            AutoGenerateRows="False"
            DataKeyNames="HolidayID"
            DataSourceID="HolidaysDS" 
            DefaultMode="Insert" 
            CssClass="dView"
            HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" 
            FieldHeaderStyle-CssClass="fieldHeader"
            AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alternating"
            CommandRowStyle-CssClass="command" 
            PagerStyle-CssClass="page"
            FooterStyle-CssClass="footer" 
            OnItemInserted="dvHolidays_ItemInserted"
            OnItemInserting="dvHolidays_ItemInserting">
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alternating" />
            <CommandRowStyle CssClass="command" />
            <FieldHeaderStyle CssClass="fieldHeader" />
            <Fields>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HolidayID" HeaderText="HolidayID" 
                    InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="HolidayID" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Year: " SortExpression="HYear">
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHolidayYear" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Year") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="YearRequiredValidator" runat="server" ValidationGroup="InsertValidationControls" ControlToValidate="txtHolidayYear" 
                            ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="YearLengthValidator" runat="server" ValidationGroup="InsertValidationControls" ControlToValidate="txtHolidayYear"
                            ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{4,4}$" ErrorMessage="The Year can only be numeric(0-9), and has to be four digits."></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start Date: " SortExpression="HStartDate">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHolidayStartEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HStartDate") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="HolidayStartEditRequiredValidator" runat="server" ValidationGroup="EditValidationControls" ControlToValidate="txtHolidayStartEdit"
                            ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHolidayStartInsert" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StartDate") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="HolidayStartInsertRequiredValidator" runat="server" ValidationGroup="InsertValidationControls" ControlToValidate="txtHolidayStartInsert"
                            ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="End Date: " SortExpression="HEndDate">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHolidayEndEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HEndDate") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="HolidayEndEditRequiredValidator" runat="server" ValidationGroup="EditValidationControls" ControlToValidate="txtHolidayEndEdit"
                            ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:CompareValidator ID="HolidayRangeCheckEdit" runat="server" ValidationGroup="EditValidationControls" ControlToValidate="txtHolidayEndEdit" ErrorMessage="End Date must be after Start Date."
                            ControlToCompare="txtHolidayStartEdit" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" Type="Date"></asp:CompareValidator>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox  ID="txtHolidayEndInsert" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EndDate") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox> 
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="HolidayEndInsertRequiredValidator" runat="server" ValidationGroup="InsertValidationControls" ControlToValidate="txtHolidayEndInsert"
                            ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:CompareValidator ID="HolidayRangeCheckInsert" runat="server" ValidationGroup="InsertValidationControls" ControlToValidate="txtHolidayEndInsert"
                            ControlToCompare="txtHolidayStartInsert" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" Type="Date" ErrorMessage="Please enter an End Date that is after the Start Date."></asp:CompareValidator>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description: " SortExpression="HDescription">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHolidayDescriptionEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HDescription") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHolidayDescriptionInsert" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="true" 
                    ValidationGroup="InsertValidationControls"/>
            </Fields>
            <FooterStyle CssClass="footer" />
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="header" />
            <PagerStyle CssClass="page" />
            </asp:DetailsView>
        <asp:Label ID="lblInsertUniqueError" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
            Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="Red" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
       </asp:View>
```

Comment: Are you databinding the `GridView` on postback?

Comment: I am databinding the datasource for the gridview in my RowUpdated event.

protected void gvHolidays_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        HolidaysDS.DataBind();
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe problem the whole time was that I was using bound fields in the gridview instead of template fields.  Here is my updated code for anyone else who comes across this problem.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_Holidays" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="HolidayID" 
            DataSourceID="HolidaysDS" 
            AllowSorting="True"  
            CssClass="gvhours"
            HeaderStyle-CssClass="header"
            AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alternating"
            SortedAscendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="sortasc-header"
            SortedDescendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="sortdesc-header"
            CommandRowStyle-CssClass="command" 
            PagerStyle-CssClass="page"
            OnRowUpdating="gvHolidays_RowUpdating">
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alternating" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" 
                    ValidationGroup="EditValidationControls" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HolidayID" HeaderText="HolidayID" InsertVisible="False" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="HolidayID" Visible="False" 
                    ShowHeader="False"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HYear" HeaderText="Year" SortExpression="HYear" Visible="false" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start Date" SortExpression="HStartDate" >
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHolidayStartEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HStartDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="HolidayStartEditRequiredValidator" runat="server" ValidationGroup="EditValidationControls" ControlToValidate="txtHolidayStartEdit"
                            ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblStartItem" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HStartDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' ></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="End Date" SortExpression="HEndDate" >
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHolidayEndEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HEndDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="HolidayEndEditRequiredValidator" runat="server" ValidationGroup="EditValidationControls" ControlToValidate="txtHolidayEndEdit"
                            ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:CompareValidator ID="HolidayRangeCheckEdit" runat="server" ValidationGroup="EditValidationControls" ControlToValidate="txtHolidayEndEdit" ErrorMessage="End Date must be after Start Date."
                            ControlToCompare="txtHolidayStartEdit" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" Type="Date"></asp:CompareValidator>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblEndItem" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HEndDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HDescription" HeaderText="Description" 
                    SortExpression="HDescription" />
            </Columns>
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="header" />
            <PagerStyle CssClass="page" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortasc-header" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortdesc-header" />
        </asp:GridView>
```